# Why I get a TypeError: PySide2.QtCore.QStringListModel.setData(): not enough arguments

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

I try to add new string into QStringListModel in PySide2 like this

```
self.model = QStringListModel()
n = self.model.rowCount()
self.model.insertRow(n)
i = self.model.index(n,0)
self.model.setData(index= i,value='Hello World!!',role=Qt.EditRole)
```

it runs ok until insertRow(),
but I get a
**TypeError: PySide2.QtCore.QStringListModel.setData(): not enough arguments**
at the last line.
since I fill all the arguments in this function.
How this error heppend and How to solve it ?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

> QStringListModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::EditRole)
>
> Reimplements: QAbstractItemModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role).
>
> Sets the data for the specified role in the item with the given index in the model, to the provided value.
>
> The dataChanged() signal is emitted if the item is changed. Returns true after emitting the dataChanged() signal.

Change

```
self.model.setData(index= i,value='Hello World!!',role=Qt.EditRole)
```

to

```
self.model.setData(i, 'Hello World!!', role=Qt.EditRole)
```